# ngrx/entity problem with selecting data inside a feature

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx-store, ngrx-entity

I'm trying to create a library which has a feature-state and a combined reducer.

My feature reducer looks like this:

index.ts

```js
export const storageFeatureKey = 'storage';

export interface StorageState {
  [fromBookEntries.bookEntriesFeatureKey]: fromBookEntries.State
}

export function reducers(state: StorageState | undefined, action: Action) {
  return combineReducers({
    [fromBookEntries.bookEntriesFeatureKey]: fromBookEntries.reducer
  })(state, action);
}
```

bookEntriesFeatures looks like this:

book-entries.reducer.ts

```js
export const bookEntriesFeatureKey = 'book-entries';

export interface State extends EntityState<WarehouseBookEntry> {
  selectedEntryId: number;
}

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<WarehouseBookEntry> = createEntityAdapter<WarehouseBookEntry>({
  selectId: (entry) => entry.id
});

export const initialState: State = adapter.getInitialState({
  selectedEntryId: null
});

export const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(...),
  on(...)
);

export const getSelectedEntryId = (state: State) => state.selectedEntryId;

const {
  selectIds,
  selectEntities,
  selectAll,
  selectTotal
} = adapter.getSelectors();

export const getBookEntriesIds = selectIds;
export const getBookEntriesEntities = selectEntities;
export const getAllBookEntries = selectAll;
export const getTotalBookEntries = selectTotal;
```

In my feature module I import StoreModule.forFeature() with my feature key and the feature reducer.

No I'm trying to select an entry based on a selected id. Therefore i fire an action, which successfully adding the id of the selected entry to my book-entries state.

To select the selected entry I have following selector inside my feature selectors:

index.ts

```js
export const selectSelectedBookEntry = createSelector(
  fromBookEntries.getBookEntriesEntities, // fromBookEntries is in my bookEntriesFeature
  selectSelectedBookEntryId, // simply returns the selected id
  (entries, selectedId) => {
    //console.log(entries, selectedId)
    //console.log("fired");
    return entries && entries[selectedId];
  }
);
```

When loading entries via another dispatched action, the selector is only called onces (before the data loaded). I found out that when I create the selectors from my bookEntriesAdapter inside my feature selectors, it works. Like this:

index.ts

```js
export const selectStorageState = createFeatureSelector<StorageState>(
  storageFeatureKey
);

export const selectBookEntriesState = createSelector(
  selectStorageState,
  state => state[fromBookEntries.bookEntriesFeatureKey]
);

const {
  selectIds,
  selectEntities: selectBookEntriesEntities,
  selectAll,
  selectTotal
} = fromBookEntries.adapter.getSelectors(selectBookEntriesState);

export const selectAllBookEntries = createSelector(
  selectBookEntriesState,
  selectAll
)

export const selectSelectedBookEntry = createSelector(
  selectBookEntriesEntities,
  selectSelectedBookEntryId,
  (entries, selectedId) => {
    //console.log(entries, selectedId)
    //console.log("fired");
    return entries && entries[selectedId];
  }
);
```

But why? I'm a little lost trying to understand why this does not work the other way around.

The above example that does not work is from the official ngrx doc (https://ngrx.io/guide/entity/adapter). The one thats working is from ngrx/platform example code (https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/projects/example-app/src/app/books/reducers/index.ts).

I don't think it's necessary, but I do not extend the root-app-store-state since I have no access to it, because it's a library (Trying to get around domain-driven-design and I created a feature-lib to handle this kind of problem). Or might this be the problem?

I would appreciate it if someone could explain this a little more.

Comment: please share code of your selectors.

Answer (score 3):

In your code you miss `createFeatureSelector` and its integration.

It's important to select your feature state first from the global state and then select data you need.

when you use selectors like that

```
const {
  selectIds,
  selectEntities,
  selectAll,
  selectTotal
} = adapter.getSelectors();

export const getBookEntriesEntities = selectEntities;
```

they know nothing about `StoreModule.forFeature(FEATURE_KEY)` and it's your responsibility to narrow global state for them.

For that you need `createFeatureSelector`, it selects your feature from the global state.

Therefore to use `getBookEntriesEntities` you need first to select your feature and then to pass this data into `getBookEntriesEntities`.

```js
const selectMyFeature = createFeatureSelector(FEATURE_KEY);

const selectMyFeatureEntities = createSelector(
  selectMyFeature,
  getBookEntriesEntities,
);
```

now when we use `store.select(selectMyFeatureEntities)` it knows how to select data from the feature.

The right code in your case would be

```js
const {
  selectIds,
  selectEntities,
  selectAll,
  selectTotal
} = adapter.getSelectors();

// put here feature name from .forFeature
const selectMyFeature = createFeatureSelector(FEATURE_KEY);

export const selectMyFeatureBooks = createSelector(
  selectMyFeature,
  state => state[fromBookEntries.bookEntriesFeatureKey]
);

export const getSelectedEntryId = createSelector(
  selectMyFeatureBooks,
  (state: State) => state.selectedEntryId,
);

export const getBookEntriesIds = createSelector(
  selectMyFeatureBooks,
  selectIds,
);
export const getBookEntriesEntities = createSelector(
  selectMyFeatureBooks,
  selectEntities,
);
export const getAllBookEntries = createSelector(
  selectMyFeatureBooks,
  selectAll,
);
export const getTotalBookEntries = createSelector(
  selectMyFeatureBooks,
  selectTotal
);
```

and now `selectSelectedBookEntry` will work as expected.